# Randomly add a 'ul' list of images

Tags: images

I'm developing a photo gallery WP site. I would like to add "ul" list of images that are randomly picked from the gallery.

How would I randomly pick a number of images from the media library.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your theme's *functions.php* file will let you use a shortcode ( `[wpse73055-random-images]` ) with an optional `num` parameter (i.e. `[wpse73055-random-images num=5]` to display 5 random images).

```
function wpse73055_get_random_images( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'num' => 10
    ), $atts ) );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => $num,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    $images_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $images = $images_query->posts;

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        $output .= '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_link( $image->ID ) . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'wpse73055-random-images', 'wpse73055_get_random_images' );
```

- [`wp_get_attachment_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)
- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: Querying for all posts is risky (simply put - what if there is million of images? instantly fried server). Would be better to `'orderby' => 'rand'` to fetch limited randomized set at database stage.

Comment: That was a bit daft indeed. Edited. Would not have minded, had you done so in the first place.

Comment: Some evenings I am like immaterial ghost that barely has enough left in it to wail at mortals so they fix their stuff. :)

Comment: I've added the above code to the functions.php and used [wpse73055-random-images] where I would like the images. I'm not getting any images - is there anything else I should be doing.

Comment: Got it working now put the images are low quaintly. How would I control which size image is used?

Comment: Above I provided a link to the codex page of `wp_get_attachment_link`, adjust the second argument `$size`. Defaults to `'thumbnail'`.